# Parent class properities

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

If i have a parent class or interface and 2 child classes which inherit from the parent or implement the interface and i have common properties in the parent but there are some properties different in each child. Should i gather all properties in the parent class/interface  or separate them?

```
abstract class Customer
{
  string name { get; set; }
}

class GoldCustomer : Customer
{
  string Address { get; set;}
}

class SilverCustomer : Customer
{
  string Telephone { get; set;}
}
```

If i  separate them then and create a reference from the parent pointing to the child then i can't access the separated child properties

```
Customer c = new GoldCustomer();
c.Address // error
```

Which is more correct architecture and not violating any design patterns?

```
abstract class Customer
{
  string name { get; set; }
  string Address { get; set;}
  string Telephone { get; set;}
}

class GoldCustomer : Customer
{

}

class SilverCustomer : Customer
{

}


Customer c = new GoldCustomer();
c.Address = "";
```

Comment: It depends on the exact circumstances. Design your classes in a way that you don't need to violate the Liskov Substitution Principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) If you find that difficult, consider composition instead of inheritance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: This is too broad question and as itsme86 said, it depends on specific curcumstances. Both aproaches could be correct, it just really depends on what you want to do. Just try to think beforehand what you actually need so you don't make needless dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the approach from @itsme86 a little bit, so that I have the `Address` or `Telephone` only on one specific `ContactInfo`:

```
public class Customer<T> where T : IContactInfo
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public T ContactInfo { get; }
}

public interface IContactInfo
{  }

public class GoldContactInfo : IContactInfo
{
    public string Address { get; }
}

public class SilverContactInfo : IContactInfo
{
    public string Telephone { get; }
}

public class GoldCustomer : Customer<GoldContactInfo>
{
     // Here does the GoldCustomer have a GoldContactInfo
}

public class SilverCustomer : Customer<SilverContactInfo>
{
     // Here does the SilverCustomer have a SilverContactInfo
}
```

Comment: Okay, so how does a caller ask for a customer's address? You're likely going to fall back on something like `if (typeof(T) == typeof(GoldContactInfo)`. Unless you've got another trick? It seems too tightly bound to me. You don't want the `Customer` class to have to know anything about the `ContactInfo` type. That's the whole point of composition.

Comment: @itsme86 First of all I have never said that the type `T` is not needed. I only changed your approach because like you mentioned before the question is broad and I wanted to show some different approach. Second I  think composition has much more benefits than just "You don't want the Customer class to have to know anything about the ContactInfo class." See this five reasons e.g. http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2013/06/why-favor-composition-over-inheritance-java-oops-design.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inheritance, I'd probably opt for a separate set of classes that contain the different contact information for the customer types:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; }
    // Other common properties
}

public abstract class ContactInfo
{
    public virtual string Address => "";
    public virtual string Telephone => "";
}

public class GoldContactInfo : ContactInfo
{
    public override string Address { get; }
}

public class SilverContactInfo : ContactInfo
{
    public override string Telephone { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about inheritance and properties, the simplest method is to think of them in term of "is-a" and "has-a".

Does a `Customer` have an `Address`?  How about a `Telephone`?  If a general `Customer` does not have an address, then the following makes no sense:

```
Customer c = new GoldCustomer();
c.Address = "";  // Customer does not have an Address property
```

The fact that the *actual* object *does* have an `Address` property is irrelevant.  You've declared it as a `Customer` variable, so the compiler treats it as such.

If *all* customers have an address and telephone, then what other properties or behaviors make a `SilverCustomer` different from a "regular" customer?  You might also find that an attribute of `Custmoer` that indicates the level is simpler as well, but it depends on the actual usage.